# Finding minimum/maximum/average values of a sequence in C++

Tags: c++, average, max, minimum

I'm creating a program that simulates the filling of a reservoir. The process is going alright so far except for the last thing I want to do which is grab the maximum, minimum, and average number of years it takes to fill the reservoir. I want to do so without the use of arrays. I think I'm close but I must be missing something simple. Forgive me, I'm just learning C++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;




int main ()
{

    string operation;
    do{
    cout << "Using the letters 's', or 'q', please indicate if you would like to run a simulation, or quit the program: " << endl;
    cin >> operation;
    } while (operation != "s" && operation != "q");
    string reservoir_name; // Creating variables for reservoir
    double reservoir_capacity;
    double outflow;
    double inflow_min;
    double inflow_max;

    if (operation == "q")
    {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "This was a triumph . . ." << endl;
        cout << "I'm making a note here: huge success!" << endl;
        system ("pause");
        return 0;
    }

    while (operation == "s") 
        {

                string reservoir_name; // Creating variables
                double reservoir_capacity;

                double inflow_min = 0;
                double inflow_max = 0;
                double inflow_average = inflow_min + inflow_max;
                double inflow_difference = inflow_max - inflow_min;
                double inflow_threshold = .9 * inflow_average/2; // Math for acceptable flow threshold.



                cout << "What is the name of the reservoir?" << endl;
                cin.ignore ();
                getline (cin,reservoir_name); // Grab whole string for reservoir name.
                cout << "What is the capacity of the reservoir in MAF (Millions of Acre Feet)?" << endl;
                cin >> reservoir_capacity;
                cout << "What is the minimum inflow?" << endl;
                cin >> inflow_min;
                cout << "What is the maximum inflow?" << endl;
                cin >> inflow_max;
                cout << "What is the required outflow?" << endl;
                cin >> outflow;
                cout << endl;
                inflow_average = inflow_min + inflow_max;
                inflow_threshold = .9 * inflow_average/2; // Calculate threshold for too much outflow.
                cin.ignore ();

                if (outflow > inflow_threshold) // Check for unacceptable outflow levels.
                {
                    cout << "Warning! The outflow is over 90% of the average inflow. Simulation aborted. Returning to main menu." << endl << endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    const int number_simulations = 10;
                    cout << endl;
                    cout << "Reservoir name: " << reservoir_name << endl;
                    cout << "Capacity of reservoir in MAF: " << reservoir_capacity << endl;
                    cout << "Maximum inflow in MAF: " << inflow_max << endl;
                    cout << "Minimum inflow in MAF: " << inflow_min << endl;
                    cout << "Required outflow in MAF: " << outflow << endl << endl;

                    cout << "Running simulation . . ." << endl << endl;
                    srand (time(0));
                    const int sentinel = -1;
                    int minimum = sentinel;
                    int maximum = sentinel;
                    int years_total;
                    for (int i = 1; i <= number_simulations; i++) // Loop should run the filling simulation 10 times.
                    {

                        int years = 0;
                        double fill_level = 0;
                        for (years; fill_level < reservoir_capacity; years++ ) // Loop should simulate filling reservoir using random inflow values between inflow_min and inflow_max.
                        {

                            double r = rand() * 1.0 / RAND_MAX;
                            double x = inflow_min + (inflow_max - inflow_min) * r;// SHOULD be between minimum inflow and maximum inflow.
                            // cout << "Random Number x :" << x << endl; WAS USED TO CHECK IF RANDOM NUMBER WAS CHANGING
                            fill_level = fill_level + x - outflow;
                            if (fill_level < 0)
                            {
                            fill_level = 0; // Prevent fill level from going negative.
                            }
                            //cout << "Fill level is " << fill_level << endl; TO CHECK THE CHANGE IN FILL LEVEL PER ITERATION
                            if (minimum == sentinel || years < minimum) // Trying to set up the method for retrieving minimum value here. Currently returning as 0.
                            {
                                minimum = years;
                            }
                            if (maximum == sentinel || years > maximum) // Trying to set up the method for retrieving maximum value here. Currently returning as 1 less than the actual maximum.
                            {
                                maximum = years;
                            }
                        }   // Simulate the change of water level.

                        cout << "Simulation " << i << ": The reservoir took " << years << " years to fill." << endl;

                    }

                        cout << "The minimum number of years needed to fill: " << minimum << endl;
                        cout << "The maximum number of years needed to fill: " << maximum << endl;
                        cout << "The average number of years needed to fill: " << years_total / 10 << endl; // Take the running total of years over 10 simulations and divide by 10. Currently returning as 0.
                }
                    cout << endl;
                    cout << "What would you like to do now?" << endl << endl; // Saving for later. The menu re-prompt message and code.
                    cout << "Using the letters 's', or 'q', please indicate if you would like to run a simulation or quit the program: " << endl;
                    cin >> operation;
                    if (operation == "q")
                    {
                        cout << endl;
                        cout << "This was a triumph . . ." << endl;
                        cout << "I'm making a note here: huge success!" << endl;
                        system ("pause");
                        return 0;
                    }
    }


    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's your current results? And what are you expecting? To test, you should use static values where you know the results instead of random values.

Comment: What is your question? Do you need help designing an algorithm? Do you want help with debugging? What is the bug? What happens if you step through the code line by line? Have you tried reducing the program to the smallest program that still demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Since we are talking about C++, I feel obliged to mention the standard C++ library operations that could (greatly) assist:

- [`std::minmax_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element) returns a pair containing the minimum and maximum of a collection (there are also `std::min_element` and `std::max_element` available).
- [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate), when initialized with 0, returns the sum of the elements of a collection; the average is not far.

Of course, this is slightly suboptimal if you wish to have the 3 at the same time, since it means two passes over the collection instead of one. However it's still O(N) time and O(1) space, and brings down the code *you* have to write significantly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add to `years_total`:

```
years_total += years;
```

You need to move the setting of `minimum` and `maximum` to *outside* the `for` loop.  You can do away with `sentinel` with a different setting of min and max.  See below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{

    string operation;
    do{
    cout << "Using the letters 's', or 'q', please indicate if you would like to run a simulation, or quit the program: " << endl;
    cin >> operation;
    } while (operation != "s" && operation != "q");
    string reservoir_name; // Creating variables for reservoir
    double reservoir_capacity;
    double outflow;
    double inflow_min;
    double inflow_max;

    if (operation == "q")
    {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "This was a triumph . . ." << endl;
        cout << "I'm making a note here: huge success!" << endl;
        system ("pause");
        return 0;
    }

    while (operation == "s") 
        {

                string reservoir_name; // Creating variables
                double reservoir_capacity;

                double inflow_min = 0;
                double inflow_max = 0;
                double inflow_average = inflow_min + inflow_max;
                double inflow_difference = inflow_max - inflow_min;
                double inflow_threshold = .9 * inflow_average/2; // Math for acceptable flow threshold.



                cout << "What is the name of the reservoir?" << endl;
                cin.ignore ();
                getline (cin,reservoir_name); // Grab whole string for reservoir name.
                cout << "What is the capacity of the reservoir in MAF (Millions of Acre Feet)?" << endl;
                cin >> reservoir_capacity;
                cout << "What is the minimum inflow?" << endl;
                cin >> inflow_min;
                cout << "What is the maximum inflow?" << endl;
                cin >> inflow_max;
                cout << "What is the required outflow?" << endl;
                cin >> outflow;
                cout << endl;
                inflow_average = inflow_min + inflow_max;
                inflow_threshold = .9 * inflow_average/2; // Calculate threshold for too much outflow.
                cin.ignore ();

                if (outflow > inflow_threshold) // Check for unacceptable outflow levels.
                {
                    cout << "Warning! The outflow is over 90% of the average inflow. Simulation aborted. Returning to main menu." << endl << endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    const int number_simulations = 10;
                    cout << endl;
                    cout << "Reservoir name: " << reservoir_name << endl;
                    cout << "Capacity of reservoir in MAF: " << reservoir_capacity << endl;
                    cout << "Maximum inflow in MAF: " << inflow_max << endl;
                    cout << "Minimum inflow in MAF: " << inflow_min << endl;
                    cout << "Required outflow in MAF: " << outflow << endl << endl;

                    cout << "Running simulation . . ." << endl << endl;
                    srand (time(0));
                    int minimum = reservoir_capacity + 10;
                    int maximum = -1;
                    int years_total;
                    for (int i = 1; i <= number_simulations; i++) // Loop should run the filling simulation 10 times.
                    {

                        int years = 0;
                        double fill_level = 0;
                        for (years; fill_level < reservoir_capacity; years++ ) // Loop should simulate filling reservoir using random inflow values between inflow_min and inflow_max.
                        {

                            double r = rand() * 1.0 / RAND_MAX;
                            double x = inflow_min + (inflow_max - inflow_min) * r;// SHOULD be between minimum inflow and maximum inflow.
                            // cout << "Random Number x :" << x << endl; WAS USED TO CHECK IF RANDOM NUMBER WAS CHANGING
                            fill_level = fill_level + x - outflow;
                            if (fill_level < 0)
                            {
                                fill_level = 0; // Prevent fill level from going negative.
                            }
                            //cout << "Fill level is " << fill_level << endl; TO CHECK THE CHANGE IN FILL LEVEL PER ITERATION
                        }   // Simulate the change of water level.

                        if (years < minimum) // Trying to set up the method for retrieving minimum value here. Currently returning as 0.
                        {
                            minimum = years;
                        }
                        if (years > maximum) // Trying to set up the method for retrieving maximum value here. Currently returning as 1 less than the actual maximum.
                        {
                            maximum = years;
                        }
                        years_total += years;
                        cout << "Simulation " << i << ": The reservoir took " << years << " years to fill." << endl;

                    }

                        cout << "The minimum number of years needed to fill: " << minimum << endl;
                        cout << "The maximum number of years needed to fill: " << maximum << endl;
                        cout << "The average number of years needed to fill: " << years_total / 10 << endl; // Take the running total of years over 10 simulations and divide by 10. Currently returning as 0.
                }
                    cout << endl;
                    cout << "What would you like to do now?" << endl << endl; // Saving for later. The menu re-prompt message and code.
                    cout << "Using the letters 's', or 'q', please indicate if you would like to run a simulation or quit the program: " << endl;
                    cin >> operation;
                    if (operation == "q")
                    {
                        cout << endl;
                        cout << "This was a triumph . . ." << endl;
                        cout << "I'm making a note here: huge success!" << endl;
                        system ("pause");
                        return 0;
                    }
    }


    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```